# Bash Script to remotely collect hostname, IP and host total memory

Tags: linux, ssh, awk, scripting, quoting

I am trying to write a scrip that will collect the hostname, IP and total memory installed on remote hosts from a list I feed into the script. The script will collect information from Redhat and Solaris machines.Below is what my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo > ip_info.output
echo -e "\n"
for host in `cat ip_adds`
do
echo "Hostname:" $host
sudo ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host "echo IP Address:; ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}'; free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $1,$2}'"
echo -e "\n"
done
```

When I run the script I get error below:

```
awk: {print ,}
awk:        ^ syntax error
awk: {print ,}
awk:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,}
awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I think the problem is with `free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $1,$2}` but not sure how to rectify it. If I run `free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $1,$2}` directly into the shell I have no issues. Just inside the script.

Comment: What is the `echo > ip_info.output` doing?

Comment: The `echo > ip_info.output` is writing nothing to the output file so that if I have to run the script again for whatever reason I dont end up with duplicate information.

Comment: Yes, but you don't seem to be using the output file anywhere, so I assume you're running the script as `script.sh > ip_info.output`, right?

Comment: no Im running it as `./script.sh | tee -a ip_info.output`. `echo > ip_info.output` clear the file for when `./script.sh | tee -a ip_info.output` is run.

Comment: But if you want to clear the file, why would you use `tee -a`? There's no reason to use `tee` at all and certainly no reason to use `tee -a`. Just run `./script.sh > ip_info.output` and that will always overwrite whatever is in the file.

Comment: `tee -a` is allowing me to see the output of the script on the screen but also write it to the files.

Comment: OK, then don't use `-a`. The `-a` tells `tee` to append to the file instead of overwriting it. If you use `./script.sh | tee ip_info.output`, then you'll still see the output in the terminal and you'll also save it to `ip_ifo.output`, overwriting anything that was already in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the final script looks like. I know it will come useful to some of you out there.

```
#!/bin/bash
for host in `cat ip_adds2`
do
echo "Hostname:" $host
sudo ssh -t -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host 'echo IP: `hostname -i`;read junk total used free shared buffers cached junk < <(free -g  | grep ^Mem);echo Memory: $total GiB'
echo -e "\n"
done
```

Answer (score 6):

This is considerably more complicated than it needs to be. Also, why would you run `ssh` with `sudo`? If you need to log into the remote as root, then you can do that (`ssh root@$host`) but it's very unlikely you would need to run ssh with `sudo` unless your ssh keys all belonged to root. Which is a pretty bad idea.

Also, on my Arch system, the command you seem to be using to get the IP returns the UID of my user:

```
$ ip route get 1
1.0.0.0 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 src 192.168.1.111 uid 1000 
    cache 
$ ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}'; 
1000
```

It does work as expected on an Ubuntu I tested:

```
$ ip route get 1
1.0.0.0 via 123.456.7.8 dev eth0  src 123.456.7.9
$ ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}'; 
123.456.7.9
```

So perhaps a more portable version of this is to print the field after `src`:

```
$ ip route get 1 | sed -nE 's/.* src ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p'
192.168.1.111
```

The errors you saw were indeed because of quoting. Since you were running `ssh $host "command"`, the double quotes around `command` cause the shell to expand any variables found inside the command (so things like awk's `$2` etc). To avoid this and pass the symbols unexpanded to awk, you need to escape the `$`.

A simpler version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshOpts="BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5"
echo > ip_info.output
echo ""                
while read host; do
    printf "Hostname:%s" $host
    ssh -o $sshOpts $host "printf 'Hostname: %s\nIP: %s\nMem: %s\n' $host "$(ip route get 1 | sed -nE 's/.* src ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p')" "$(free -m | awk '/Mem/{print $2}')""
done < ip_adds
```

Comment: Thanks for this terdon - Your script looks simpler however when I run it I am getting: 

`Hostname:eXX-XX-XX-XXXXX-01Hostname: eXX-XX-XX-XXXXX-01
IP: eth0
Mem: 3832`

Comment: Seems that the IP isnt being collected properly.

Comment: @user315468 yes, the output of `ip route get 1` can change on different systems. Try the updated answer, sorry!

Comment: thanks for your input. Much appreciated. With your help I have modified my script and now I get a really nice and neat output. My script looks like:

`#!/bin/bash
echo > ip_info.output
echo -e "\n"
for host in `cat ip_adds1`
do
sudo ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host "printf 'Hostname: %s\nIP: %s\nMem: %s\n' $host "$(ip route get 1 | sed -nE 's/.* src ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p')" "$(free -m | awk '/Mem/{print $2}')""
echo -e "\n"
done`

Out put is now:

`Hostname: eXX-XX-XX-XXXXX-XX
IP: XX.XX.XX.XXX
Mem: 3832`

Comment: @user315468 please consider incorporating the other changes I've made. The `while read ... < file` loop is safer than the `for` and a better way to parse files in general and the `echo -e "\n"` is just a more complicated way of writing `echo ""`, there's no reason to use it. In fact, it would be even simpler to not use echo at all and just add a `\n` to the beginning of the `printf` command, but that's up to you.

Comment: I have just run your script and realised that the only command that is getting executed remotely is `hostname` IP and memory are being executed on the local machine. Can you have another look? Thanks

Comment: For everyone else the below script works now and executes everything remotely

`#!/bin/bash
echo > ip_info.output
echo -e "\n"
for host in `cat ip_adds1`
do
echo "Hostname:" $host
sudo ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host "ip route get 255.255.255.255 | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\d{1,3}.){4}'; free -m | grep -oP '\d+' | head -n 1"
echo -e "\n"
done`

Answer (score 3):

I have found an answer for this. It was to do with escaping so I added \ before $1 and $2 as per below:

```
free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print \$1,\$2}
```